# Power of sums of matrices

Tags: matrices, power-series

What is the theory behind the following expression, where A + B represents square matrices nxn

[image: Matrix sums to the power of 3]

I know how it is done in algebra but how to arrive at this expression? Obviously binomial theorem does not hold..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Matrices are non-commutative in general with respect to multiplication. Thus the order of multiplication must be preserved when expanding powers of sums of matrices.

$(A+B)^3$ is really $(A+B)(A+B)(A+B)$, and the expansion is determined by picking one term from each factor and combining them *in order*.

Answer (score 2):

It's the distributive law, applied a whole bunch of times. For raising to the second power, and writing out all the steps:

$$(A+B)^2 = (A+B)(A+B) = A(A+B) + B(A+B) = AA + AB + BA + BB$$

Since you can't replace $BA$ with $AB$ for matrices (in general), that's as far as you can go with simplifying, except for collecting runs of the same matrix as a power (e.g. $AA = A^2$). Can you see how this would work when you multiply by $(A+B)$ one more time?